# Array with the number of times that appears

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, opencv, arraylist

**`print(exit)`** prints the direction of the cardinal points between two points!!!!!
**`print(exit.count('N'))`** counts the number of times North appears!!!!
**`print(dist(x,y,x+grad_x,y+grad_y))`** shows the distance between these two points!!!!!

I would like to know how to make an array of type `['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'W']` in which the values were the number of times each cardinal point appears

CODE

```
for x,y in new_points:
    cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 10, (0, 255,), 1)

    if vector_points.size != 0:
        grad_x, grad_y = x-vector_points[i][0], y-vector_points[i][1]
        cv2.arrowedLine(frame, (x,y),(x+grad_x, y+grad_y) , (0,255,255), 1)
        exit = direcao(x+grad_x, x, y+grad_y, y)
        print(exit)
        print(exit.count('N'))
        print(dist(x,y,x+grad_x,y+grad_y))
        #tmp.append((dist(x,y,x+grad_x,y+grad_y)))
        #print(tmp)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Okay, you already know how to get the desired result for the north direction. I assume you can use the same technique to get all the other directions, and then put them into a list. What's the problem?

Comment: the print appears to me
in loop with different values and positions`N`
                                          `1`
                                          `0.8800021212` one on each line.
how to pick up all those that appear in that respective location, ex: 'N' and we add them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with the methods you're using if I'm understanding you problem I can tell my solution would be a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
directions = ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'W']

for x,y in new_points:
    cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 10, (0, 255,), 1)

    if vector_points.size != 0:
        grad_x, grad_y = x-vector_points[i][0], y-vector_points[i][1]
        cv2.arrowedLine(frame, (x,y),(x+grad_x, y+grad_y) , (0,255,255), 1)
        exit = direcao(x+grad_x, x, y+grad_y, y)
        print(exit)

        for direction in directions:
            # this assumes exit.count() returns an int
            counts[direction] += exit.count(direction)
        print(dist(x,y,x+grad_x,y+grad_y))
        #tmp.append((dist(x,y,x+grad_x,y+grad_y)))
        #print(tmp)
    i+=1

for direction, count in counts.items():
    print(f'{direction} appears a total of {count} times.')
```

If you want to know the number of times for each individual point in `new_points` you just need to create a new `defaultdict` on each iteration of the loop and append it to a `list`.

You can also just assign it to an array as you were asking.

```
directions = ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW', 'W']
counts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for x,y in new_points:
    cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 10, (0, 255,), 1)

    if vector_points.size != 0:
        grad_x, grad_y = x-vector_points[i][0], y-vector_points[i][1]
        cv2.arrowedLine(frame, (x,y),(x+grad_x, y+grad_y) , (0,255,255), 1)
        exit = direcao(x+grad_x, x, y+grad_y, y)
        print(exit)

        for elem, direction in enumerate(directions):
            counts[elem] += exit.count(direction)

        print(dist(x,y,x+grad_x,y+grad_y))
    i+=1

print(counts)
```

Comment: I think it worked. by the way, is it possible to just be with the last print of the for ?? and pass the "string" to array?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: For example:
`N appears a total of 13 times.
NE appears a total of 0 times.
E appears a total of 0 times.
SE appears a total of 0 times.
S appears a total of 1 times.
SW appears a total of 0 times.
W appears a total of 108 times.
NW appears a total of 12 times.
N appears a total of 13 times.
NE appears a total of 0 times.
E appears a total of 0 times.
SE appears a total of 0 times.
S appears a total of 1 times.
SW appears a total of 0 times.
W appears a total of 113 times.
NW appears a total of 12 times.`

 i just want the last 8 positions and put it in array [N,NE,E]...

Comment: Is this what it returns now? Or is this what you want? I have no way of knowing without knowing what is in `new_points`. When you say you want the last 8 positions do you mean the last 8 directions or the last 8 `new_points`?

Comment: this is what returns now, basically I select points in a video and track them, and the newpoinst are those points,
what I wanted to return was that but only the final sum of the 8 directions,
and then put in a array a variable that gives the last "counts" (number) of each position, it's a bit difficult to explain sincerely, I don't know if you understand

Comment: That is a final sum of positions. For example, `print(counts['N'])` will return `13` which is a sum of all the amounts `exit.count('N')` returned for all the `new_points`.

Comment: it was more to be able to use, as I would put in an array ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW'], the maximum number of variable counting, as it would always be changing.
how would you put the results in that array?

Comment: Are you familiar with python dictionaries?

Comment: Ok what you are describing is a dictionary, which is why I used one. In an array or python `list` you access the first element like so `my_array[0]`. Python dictionaries work the same way but you can "name" an element anything. for example, you can name an element `'N'` which is what I did. So `counts['N']` gives you the `'N'` element of the `counts` dictionary or array.

Comment: so to have only the last 8 in an array how would it be?

Comment: Now `counts` has every direction. Say `exit.count('N')` equals 4 for your first `new_point`. `counts['N']` will then equal 4. if the next `exit.count('N')` equals 5 `counts['N']` will then equal 9.

Comment: Does this give you what you want? `my_array = [i for i in counts.values()]` `print(my_array)`

Comment: I added the array part to the answer as well.

Comment: how I average the displacement in each position and present it in an array of the type ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW'], where in N is the average of the displacement towards North, in E and that is the average of displacement towards East ... etc, im trying but i cant